# return false wont stop refreshing the page plus no error messages printed

Tags: javascript

This is my html code where i call a validate function to check for empty fields in a form.

```
 <form id="myForm" onsubmit= "doThese()">
```

And here is my javascript function which checks if any fields are empty and prints a message returning false or if everything is ok switches to the next page.

```
 <script>
 function doThese(){

    var i = document.getElementById("txt_name").value;     
    var y= document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var b=document.getElementById("txt_email").value;
    var c=document.getElementById("pass1").value;
    var d=document.getElementById("pass2").value;
    var mess.document.getElementById("errorMsg");
if(i==null || i== "",y==null || y== "",b==null || b== "",c==null || c== "",d==null || d== ""){
mess.style.color= "#ff6666";
mess.innerHTML="Please fill all the fields";
return false;
}
else{
parent.location='arxiki.html';
}
}
</script>
```

I've tried anything i could find but nothing would work.The page is still refreshing and no error messages would be printed even if when i submitted the form with all empty fields.Im thinking that it doesnt reach the function in the first place but i can't find a reason for that.. Any ideas ??

Comment: You need to `onsubmit="return doThese()"`

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast..Did both..Still wont work :S

Comment: Have you checked your `if` condition? The comma operator is a common source of errors: it only returns the RHS value. What you have is only checking `d` and discarding the other 3 variables

Comment: I changed it to || without commas but even if that would be the case then it should work properly for an empty field "d" but still behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

Following Code will work fine for you

HTML Form Code

```
 <form id="myForm" onsubmit="return doThese();">
```

Java Script

```
<script>
    function doThese(){
    //Response.Write("alert('Check Point One!');");
    var i = document.getElementById("txt_name").value;     
    var y= document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var b=document.getElementById("txt_email").value;
    var c=document.getElementById("pass1").value;
    var d=document.getElementById("pass2").value;
    var mess=document.getElementById("errorMsg");
    //Response.Write("alert('Check Point two!');");
if(i==null || i== ""|| i== " "||y==null || y== ""||b==null || b== ""|| b== " "||c==null || c== ""|| c== " "||d==null || d== ""|| d== " ")
{
//Response.Write("alert('Check Point three!');");
mess.style.color= "#ff6666";
mess.innerHTML="Please fill all the fields";
return false;
}
else{
parent.location='arxiki.html';
}
}
</script>
```

**Replacements**

Replace `,` with `||` in **`IF Condition`**

Add another condition  `xxx== " "` Because sometimes it seems to be empty but field have a space in it

`onsubmit="return doThese();"`  Instead of `onsubmit="doThese()"`

Un-comment the `//Response.Write("alert('______');");` to check if the function reached at this point

Comment: I tried both changes and stil wouldn't work. Is there a reason why it would not enter my "doThese()" function in the first place ?

Comment: @NLD Updated The Answer with commented **Response.Write("----");** un-comment points to check if function is called & reached at that point

Comment: i've added an alert message in the first line of the function and it doesn't show. So that would mean it doesn't enter the function but why ?

Comment: Im stupid..it was a syntax error.. this line                                                                      var mess.document.getElementById("errorMsg"); should be like      var mess=document.getElementById("errorMsg");

Comment: Im sorry for the incovenience i've cause..really and thanks for your help :)